# Problem with Hudson-JIRA-Perforce integration

Tags: hudson, perforce, jira, jenkins

I'm looking at using the Hudson JIRA plugin to post a JIRA comment on each build. The SCM I'm using is perforce which is already linked to the JIRA tasks using perforce jobs. I can see that the JIRA story (e.g. PROJ-001) is visible through the perforce plugin when clicking on the changelist number in the build reports.

I'm having problems getting the Hudson JIRA plugin to work as it appears to expect the JIRA story in the change text rather than using the perforce job reference.

Note, manually adding the JIRA story into the changetext for every commit is not an option, but I was wondering whether any had any ideas short of extending the JIRA plugin itself.

Comment: I ended up extending the jira plugin by modifying the hudson.plugins.jira.Updater#findIssues method by checking if any change in the changeset is of type hudson.plugins.perforce.PerforceChangeLogEntry and getting the list of jobs (which are equivalent to the Jira storys) through that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any of these???

http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/JIRA+Plugin

https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/11858

Comment: I am already using the JIRA plugin, but this does not recognise the JIRA Story which is specified in the "change.job" property on the PerforceChangeLogEntry, rather than in the change description.  The second link points to integrating Hudson into JIRA, which is not what the question was about.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [Marvelution JIRA Hudson Integration](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/11181)? I tried it and it worked perfect.

Comment: Did you try it with Perforce as the SCM?

Comment: No, I haven't, but I tried it to integrate Hudson and JIRA and it worked like a charm, so I recommend you to try it with Perfoce

Comment: The trouble that I was having was directly related to the fact that the perforce integration in Hudson stores the story number differently than other scms so to get the integration of the standard jira plugin to work I had to patch it myself, so I'm not actively looking for a solution at the moment but would be interested in hearing about off the shelf alternatives. If I get some time I'll give marvelution a try.